# Trigger a modal if User is Unauthorized in vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I saw [this](https://medium.com/@rmmmsy/creating-and-animating-a-modal-component-as-a-child-route-using-vue-41a275a51d0c) post on medium and tried to apply it on my project.

What I want to happen is that, check if a user is authorized to access a route and if the user is not authorized, a modal should appear.

So this is what I did on my routes:

```
function isAuthorized(data) {
  return data;
}
function isAdmin(to, from, next) {
  const isUserAdmin = store.state.authentication.isAdmin;
  if (!isUserAdmin) {
    next(false);
    isAuthorized(true);
  } else {
    isAuthorized(false);
    next();
  }
}

const router = new Router({
  ...
  routes: [
  {
  path: '/admin',
  component: Sidebar,
  meta: { showModal: isAuthorized },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'sample',
      name: 'Sample',
      component: Sample,
      beforeEnter: isAdmin,
      meta: { title: 'Sample Page' },
    },
  ...
```

and on my `Sidebar.Vue`

```
UnauthorizedModal(:show-modal="showUnauthModal"
                  @toggle-modal="toggleModal")

export default {
  name: 'Sidebar',
  components: {
    UnauthorizedModal,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showUnauthModal: this.$route.meta.showModal,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.meta'({ showModal }) {
      this.showUnauthModal = showModal;
    },
  },
```

and my UnauthorizedModal

```
<template lang="pug">
b-modal.simple-modal(
  :active="showModal"
  scroll="keep"
  @close="toggleModal"
)
  .modal-container
    header
      h1
      | Unauthorized
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'UnauthorizedModal',
  props: {
    showModal: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggleModal() {
      this.$emit('toggle-modal');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Now when I try it, I get this error on my console.

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "showModal". Expected Boolean, got Undefined in UnauthorizedModal.vue

meaning that my modal is not getting the data from my routes.

I don't need the page to redirect to anywhere, I just want to display a modal when the user is not authorized in that route.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your child component (`sample`), there is no `meta.showModal`, so it's `undefined` if you access to child component.

You can try adding `showModal` to child component

```
const router = new Router({
  ...
  routes: [
  {
  path: '/admin',
  component: Sidebar,
  meta: { showModal: false },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'sample',
      name: 'Sample',
      component: Sample,
      beforeEnter: isAdmin,
      meta: { title: 'Sample Page', showModal: false },
    },
```

I'm not sure you can mutate the meta data of router in beforeEnter or not. But you can try

```
function isAdmin(to, from, next) {
  const isUserAdmin = store.state.authentication.isAdmin;
  if (!isUserAdmin) {
    next(false);
    to.meta = {
      ...to.meta,
      showModal: true
    }
  } else {
     to.meta = {
      ...to.meta,
      showModal: true
    }
    next();
  }
}
```